# mypy importlib module functions

Tags: python-3.x, mypy

I am using importlib to import modules at runtime. These modules are plugins for my application and must implement 1 or more module-level functions. I have started adding type annotations to my applications and I get an error from mypy stating

> Module has no attribute "generate_configuration"

where "generate_configuration" is one of the module functions.

In this example, the module is only required to have a generate_configuration function in it. The function takes a single dict argument.

```
def generate_configuration(data: Dict[str, DataFrame]) -> None: ...
```

I have been searching around for how to specify the interface of a module but all I can find are class interfaces. Can someone point me to some documentation showing how to do this? My google-fu is failing me on this one.

The code that loads this module is shown below. The error is generated by the last line.

```
plugin_directory = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(directory), 'Configuration-Generation-Plugins')
plugins = (
    module_file
    for module_file in Path(plugin_directory).glob('*.py')
)
sys.path.insert(0, plugin_directory)
for plugin in plugins:
    plugin_module = import_module(plugin.stem)
    plugin_module.generate_configuration(directory, points_list)
```

Comment: without seeing relevant code it's hard for us to know how to help you?  What does your function type signature look like and what are some adjacent lines?

Comment: @AnthonySottile I added a little more detail and the function signature. Sorry for not being more clear originally.

Comment: Can you also add the line that the error is pointing at?

Comment: Thanks for guiding me through this. I have added the code that generates the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type annotation for `importlib.import_module` simply returns `types.ModuleType`

From [the typeshed source](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/61e63293f1defa2d14020262fd3c1a190d4c457d/stdlib/3/importlib/__init__.pyi#L12):

```
def import_module(name: str, package: Optional[str] = ...) -> types.ModuleType: ...
```

This means that the revealed type of `plugin_module` is `Module` -- which doesn't have your specific attributes.

Since `mypy` is a static analysis tool, it can't know that the return value of that import has a specific interface.

Here's my suggestion:

1. Make a type interface for your module (it doesn't have to be instantiated, it'll just help mypy figure things out)

   ```
   class ModuleInterface:
       @staticmethod
       def generate_configuration(data: Dict[str, DataFrame]) -> None: ...
   ```
2. Make a function which imports your module, you may need to sprinkle `# type: ignore`, though if you use `__import__` instead of `import_module` you may be able to avoid this limitation

   ```
   def import_module_with_interface(modname: str) -> ModuleInterface:
       return __import__(modname, fromlist=['_trash'])  # might need to ignore the type here
   ```
3. Enjoy the types :)

The sample code I used to verify this idea:

```
class ModuleInterface:
    @staticmethod
    def compute_foo(bar: str) -> str: ...


def import_module_with_interface(modname: str) -> ModuleInterface:
    return __import__(modname, fromlist=['_trash'])


def myf() -> None:
    mod = import_module_with_interface('test2')
    # mod.compute_foo()  # test.py:12: error: Too few arguments for "compute_foo" of "ModuleInterface"
    mod.compute_foo('hi')
```

Comment: Thanks. This pointed me in a new direction. However, rather than creating a typed function to import the plugin module, I just added an inline type declaration. I will mark your response as the correct answer and add a new response below showing my final solution.

Comment: How would this be created if the attribute wasn't a function with a particular signature but instead  a class with attributes  str, int, float, list, dict, etc - have created a post here https://stackoverflow.com/q/69583252 which i think has this case.

Answer (score 2):

I did some more research and eventually settled on a slightly different solution which uses [typing.cast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast).

The solution still uses the static method definition from [Anthony Sottile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48981829/1518394).

```
from typing import Dict
from pandas import DataFrame

class ConfigurationGenerationPlugin(ModuleType):
@staticmethod
    def generate_configuration(directory: str, points_list: Dict[str, DataFrame]) -> None: ...
```

The code that imports the module then uses [typing.cast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast)() to set the correct type.

```
plugin_directory = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(directory), 'Configuration-Generation-Plugins')
plugins = (
    module_file
    for module_file in Path(plugin_directory).glob('*.py')
    if not module_file.stem.startswith('lib')
)
sys.path.insert(0, plugin_directory)
for plugin in plugins:
    plugin_module = cast(ConfigurationGenerationPlugin, import_module(plugin.stem))
    plugin_module.generate_configuration(directory, points_list)
```

I am not sure how I feel about having to add the ConfigurationGenerationPlugin class or the cast() call to the code just to make mypy happy. However, I am going to stick with it for now.

Comment: You don't think adding the class definition and the explicit cast improves readability and transparency?  I sure do!

Comment: The cast does not improve readability or transparency. In other languages, when we use cast, it's because we have been holding or using the object as some other type. This object is something that has never been held or used as any other type. The cast shouldn't be needed.