# How to typehint python module imported using importlib with mypy

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

Given the following files:

```py
# check_1.py
from __future__ import annotations


class Something:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a


something = Something(a="this is something")
```

and

```py
# check_2.py
from __future__ import annotations

import importlib

mod = importlib.import_module(
    "check",
    package=None,
)
attribute_name = "a"
if getattr(mod, "something", False):
    if getattr(mod.something, attribute_name, False):
        print(getattr(mod, attribute_name))
```

mypy [returns the following error](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=show-error-codes%2Cstrict&gist=5303e3ea4ab799554c9d0177af5e646f):

```
check_2.py:11: error: Module has no attribute "something"  [attr-defined]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

I'm not sure how I should go about typing this though, or whether this is a case of `type: ignore[attr-defined]` being necessary. If `ignore` is necessary, It would be good to understand why that's the case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48981829/6744133 - the type of `mod` is just `ModuleType`

Comment: @Oli thanks, i'm not sure how to apply the information in that link (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48981829/6744133)  to the example in this post though

Comment: i expect you'll need to type ignore something, as mypy probably can't read through importlib. If you want some typing, you could make a sort of header file with `Protocol`s that capture the class interface, then `cast` (perhaps with a type ignore) to the appropriate protocol. It does mean you'll have two copies of your interface

Comment: @joel yes - I have to add ignores at the moment, and I don't know how to write a Protocol here.

Comment: I find writing type stubs for mutable variables difficult, but this may suffice `class Something: a: str`

Comment: @joel i don't mean to be thick, but where's that meant to go ? `check_2.py` I presume, then what? I'm not sure what the idea is here.

Comment: Wait, hang on — @baxx, it was you who asked that previous question I linked to immediately above. How is this case different to your previous question?

Comment: @AlexWaygood [YES](https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/mobile/000/023/397/C-658VsXoAo3ovC.jpg), I'm so sorry, and yes what you've done there is exactly this, thank you (again)

Comment: (let me know if this is best to delete)