# What is the type (for mypy) of a module created with importlib?

Tags: python-3.x, mypy, python-importlib

I'm loading a module with `importlib` as such:

```py
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader
from importlib.util import spec_from_loader, module_from_spec
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Union

PathStr = Union[Path, str]

def load_module(module_path:PathStr, module_name="module"):
    """Load and return a module"""
    loader = SourceFileLoader(module_name, module_path)
    spec = spec_from_loader(loader.name, loader)
    module = module_from_spec(spec)
    loader.exec_module(module)
    return module
```

What is the type of the module returned by the function? I cannot figure it out.

Comment: might [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48976499/5986907) help?

Comment: at first sight, it looks like... so hard to dig out. Good catch!

Comment: You can use `reveal_type(module)` to make mypy report the inferred type during type checking.

Comment: @Wombatz ... you can, indeed. But it revealed `Any` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This similar answer say it all:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48981829/1603480

Here is a summary for persistent information:The type annotation for `importlib.import_module` simply returns `types.ModuleType`

From [the typeshed source](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/61e63293f1defa2d14020262fd3c1a190d4c457d/stdlib/3/importlib/__init__.pyi#L12):

```
def import_module(name: str, package: Optional[str] = ...) -> types.ModuleType: ...
```

... And then the author of the solution provides some suggestions to help `mypy`